# Is there any way to delete single message from ejabberd archive

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-hooks

I am using ejabberd for my chat app, I want to add delete single message feature. Is there any way in ejabberd 18.03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you refer to the archive stored by mod_mam, which implements XEP-0313. In the protocol I don't see any way to delete messages, see https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html Also in mod_mam.erl I see no administrative way to delete individual messages.